# Would this be allowed to happen in real life?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, realism, spider-man-far-from-home

In [Spider-Man: Far From Home](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man:_Far_From_Home), the first post-credits scene, a news broadcast in a screen outside the Madison Square Garden announces and shows a video of Mysterio, before dying which was edited to make it look like Spider-Man is the real villain.

Then, the news broadcaster comes back and shows a video from a controversial website called *thedailybugle.net*, which from my understanding seems to be a parody of Alex Jones' conspiracy show.

I understand that this happens in the movie for exposition reasons, but:

Would this happen in real life? A news broadcast showing a disturbing video of a near-death situation, also taken from an unreliable controversial website on those street screens?

Comment: Just a note that "The Daily Bugle" was the name of the newspaper in Marvel comics [Ref.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daily_Bugle). The man reporting is the actor who plays J. Jonah Jameson in the Tobey Maguire version of Spider man.

Comment: You should see how media act these days. They'd do whatever to just increase their ratings. so this scene is kinda normal thing to show (in some countries there'd be some restrictions, but most of the countries don't have something like that)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[The Daily Bugle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daily_Bugle) can be controversial but is not considered unreliable in the Marvel comics. It's a famous tabloid in the Spider-Man comics and is making its first appearance in MCU in the form of thedailybugle.net.

There is a history of J. Jonah Jameson (the publisher of The Daily Bugle) to publish anything anti-Spider-Man. So it should not come as a shocker.

And talking about a news broadcast showing a disturbing video of a near-death situation: this is not unheard off, and with a simple google search I found:

[SKY TV pulls Australian news broadcast after 'disturbing' Christchurch shootings video shown](https://www.stuff.co.nz/business/111331018/sky-tv-pulls-australian-news-broadcast-after-disturbing-christchurch-shootings-video-shown)

[I&B Ministry bans two regional news channels for content violation](https://www.exchange4media.com/media-tv-news/i-b-ministry-bans-two-regional-news-channels-for-content-violation-87622.html)

Both cases had consequences for the channel, and I am sure many other such cases can be found. So if you ask whether or not it is allowed, then the answer is that every country has its own censorship, and sometimes news channels can surpass the allowed limitations, and may or may not be presented with consequential actions.

Comment: I thought it was perfect and fitting that they brought back J.K. Simmons for that role. :) He fits that character perfectly.